# Reveal DIV based on URL, rehide based on anchor change

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I'm currently showing and hiding a DIV based on the URL, by setting the body class name:

```
if(location.href.match("#!/~/product/category")){document.body.className+="show";}
```

And the DIV changes accordingly:

```
#showcase {
 display: none;
}

body.show  #showcase {
display: block;
}
```

Works great. Up until the AJAX cart changes the URL to `#!/~/cart`
I would like to make the DIV disappear everywhere EXCEPT the `product/category` URL, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you know how `if {} else {}` works? It would probably be easier to not use classes here. e.g. `if (...) {document.body.style.display = "block";} else {document.body.style.display = "none";}`

Comment: Or, using jQuery I want to set the css value for a DIV using jquery
`#showcase{
display: block;
}`

and based upon a .click from either of two buttons (classes are long) I want to set the `display:none`
Suggestions?

Comment: I guess the challenge is that the AJAX cart isn't triggering the script, because the page isnt reloading.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with an if-else as @HamzaKubba said.

If you'd still like to apply the relevant styles with your css you can do this:

```
// just because I have no idea what your body class usually is
// you might just hard-code something else you want
var defaultBodyClass = document.body.className

if (location.href.match('#!/~/product/category')){
  document.body.className = defaultBodyClass + ' show';
} else {
  document.body.className = defaultBodyClass;
}
```